# Icon Tab bar text color change

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How can I change the icon tab bar text color in ui5 application? I am trying to change the text color of icon Tab bar. I have two icon and based on condition I want to change 2nd icon tab bar text color.

I tried below two ways but not able to success. Below is my code of css,controller and xml:

XML

```xml
<IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://open-command-field"/>
    <IconTabFilter id="id"  icon="sap-icon://account"  design="Horizontal" 
        text="sales" key="1" enabled="false"/>

    <IconTabFilter id="id2" icon="sap-icon://action" text="purchase" key="1"
        enabled="false"/>
```

CSS code:

```html
.TextColor{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Controller:

```js
that.getView().byId("id").addStyleClass("TextColor");

//getting error like below
that.getView(...).byId(...).addStyleClass is not a function    

that.getView().byId("id").getText().fontcolor("#ff3333").//no effect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve that is probably using custom data aggregation.
In your IconTabFilter:

```
<IconTabFilter id="id"  icon="sap-icon://account"  design="Horizontal" 
    text="sales" key="1" enabled="false"> 
    <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="myTextColor" value="red" writeToDom="true"/>
    </customData>
</IconTabFilter>
```

And in your css:

```
*[data-myTextColor='red'] .sapMITBText{
    color: red !important;
}
```

In order to avoid unwanted styling, I usually put a class also to my `<App/>` tag such as

```
<App id="app" busy="{appView>/busy}" busyIndicatorDelay="{appView>/delay}" class="myApp">
```

So the css selector becomes:

```
.myApp *[data-myTextColor='red'] .sapMITBText{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IconTabFilter employs the iconColor attribute to change the colour.

It can take on a limited number of colour options - see here: [options](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.IconColor)

I prefer setting the colour using model binding:

Controller (adjust condition as required):

```
if (condition == bad) that.getView().getModel("viewModel").setProperty("/salesIconColour", "Critical");
```

View:

```
<IconTabFilter
        key="1"
        icon="sap-icon://account"
        iconColor="{viewModel>/salesIconColour}"
        text="sales"/>
```

You are also able to use inline binding expressions directly in the view (if you wish).
With the above you could influence the colour of any particular icon (sales or purchase).

Comment: I want to Change the Text Color not icon

Comment: I am trying to change the text color only

Comment: my apologies - my bad - why would you limit the colour change to the text - just out of interest? This would certainly breach design guidelines which are so "opinionated" within the context of UI5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can this in onAfterRendering. I think it is not best way.

`let iconTabFilter = document.getElementById(self.getView().byId("id").sId + "-text");
 iconTabFilter.style.cssText = "color: red !important";`